# MySQL Max() with group by and multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, max, mysql-workbench

for my studies i need to get a code working. I do have two tables:

Training:
UserID
Date
Uebung
Gewicht
Wiederholungen

Mitglied:
UserID
Name
Vorname

and i need to display the max power which you get if you multiply 'Wiederholungen' with 'Gewicht' from the 'Training' table for EACH User with the date and name.

I know there is a "problem" with max() and group by. But i'm kinda new to MySQL and i was only able to find fixes with one table and also every column already existing. I have to join two tables AND create the power column.

I tried a lot and i think this may be my best chance

```
select name, vorname, x.power from
(SELECT mitglied.UserID,max( Wiederholungen*Gewicht) as Power
FROM training join mitglied
where Uebung = 'Beinstrecker'
and training.UserID = mitglied.UserID
group by training.UserID) as x
inner join (training, mitglied)
on (training.UserID = mitglied.UserID)
and x.Power = Power;
'''

I get way too many results. I know the last statement is wrong (x.power = power) but i have no clue how to solve it.
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: It's generally* not a good idea to mix explcit JOIN and implicit "comma" join notation in a query.... and generally* a good idea to just not use the borderline archaic comma join notation at all. _(*It's ok for "initializer" type subqueries that only really have one row anyway, but that is about it.)_ Also, I see no reason your subquery even needs `mitglied`; `training` already has `userid`.

Comment: You're getting too many results because `(training, mitglied)` is actually a cartesian product of those two tables, then joined to your subquery.

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad data. I hade to translate at least the most important things for everybody to understand.

 "mitglied; training already has userid" because i need the names from the user from "mitglied"

Comment: Bad data? There's no data here

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a fairly typical question here, but I am bad a searching for previous answers so....

You "start" in a subquery, finding those max values:

```
SELECT UserID, Uebung, MAX(Gewicht*Wiederholugen) AS Power
FROM training 
WHERE Uebung = 'Beinstrecker'
GROUP BY UserID, Uebung
```

Then, you join that back to the table it came from to find the date(s) those maxes occurred:

```
( SELECT UserID, Uebung, MAX(Gewicht*Wiederholugen) AS Power
  FROM training 
  WHERE Uebung = 'Beinstrecker'
  GROUP BY UserID, Uebung
) AS maxes
INNER JOIN training AS t 
   ON maxes.UserID = t.UserID 
   AND maxes.Uebeng = t.Uebeng
   AND maxes.Power = (t.Gewicht*t.Wiederholugen)
```

Finally, you join to `mitglied` to get information for the user:

```
SELECT m.name, m.vorname, maxes.Power
FROM ( SELECT UserID, Uebung, MAX(Gewicht*Wiederholugen) AS Power
       FROM training 
       WHERE Uebung = 'Beinstrecker'
       GROUP BY UserID, Uebung
) AS maxes
INNER JOIN training AS t 
   ON maxes.UserID = t.UserID 
   AND maxes.Uebeng = t.Uebeng
   AND maxes.Power = (t.Gewicht*t.Wiederholugen)
INNER JOIN mitglied AS m ON t.UserID = m.UserID
;
```

Note: `t.Uebung = 'Beinstrecker'` could be used as a join condition instead, and might be faster; but as a matter of style I try to prevent redundant literals like that unless there is a worthwhile performance difference.

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems like it works, just one thing: i have 500 user and i get over 1000 results. Some User appear 2 or 3 times with the same power. Any idea?

Comment: If they had that power on multiple occasions, or there are multiple mitglied per userid, they will show up multiple times.

Comment: Okay, some user have the same power on two different dates. Thank you so much!